# How to solve butterfly pattern in using for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, design-patterns

I can't found the law of this butterfly like pattern.
Hope someone can help me out how to write this program.
Thank you!!!

I try to write a pyramid in the beginning , and I don't know how to solve the butterfly pattern!
this is my code  below:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
int main(void) { 
int i,j,n;
 n=5;
 for(i=0;i<=n;i++){ 
 for(j=0;j<=2*n;j++){ 
 if(abs(j-n)<i) 
    printf(" "); 
 else 
    printf("%d",j); 
 } 
  printf("\n");
  } 
  return 0;
 } –
```

[image]

Comment: please insert your trying code here

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
   int i,j,n;
   
   n=5;
   
   for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
   for(j=0;j<=2*n;j++){
   if(abs(j-n)<i)
   printf(" ");
   else
   printf("%d",j);
   }
   printf("\n"); 
   }
   return 0;
}